# Github star/unstar in API

Tags: api, github

Do you know if github has implemented their new star/unstar feature of repositories in the API yet? I can't find anything in the [documentation](http://developer.github.com) over there.

Comment: have a look at this https://starhub-notifier.duckdns.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read that document, changelog states:

> **Breaking Beta Changes**
>
> August 7, 2012
> Clarified watching/stargazing

The changeset is here:

- https://github.com/github/developer.github.com/commit/14c25df8c1a5e4e9a593d477d9e7d42b632ceb3c

Let me know if you still have problems to locate the information.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository:

> #### Star a repository
>
> ```
> PUT /user/starred/:owner/:repo
> ```
>
> #### Unstar a repository
>
> ```
> DELETE /user/starred/:owner/:repo
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's been added: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/starring/ ([history](https://github.com/github/developer.github.com/commits/master/content/v3/repos/starring.md)). There's also some [transitional stuff to deprecate the watching APIs](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-9-5-watcher-api/), if you've been using them.